# Declaration and initialisation of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm brushing up on the initialization and declaration of pointers in C.

I wrote a piece of code :

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* right=NULL;
    struct node* left=NULL;
};

struct node* newNode(int data) 
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->data = data;
    
    return temp;
}
```

which returned an error. The error is :

> expected ';' at end of declaration list
>
> ```
>    struct node* right=NULL;
> ```

I then changed the code to :

```
struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node* right;
        struct node* left;
        right = NULL;
        left  = NULL;

    };
    
    struct node* newNode(int data) 
    {
        struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
        temp->data = data;
        
        return temp;
    }
```

which returned the same error.

Finally,

I changed the code to :

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* right;
    struct node* left;
};

struct node* newNode(int data) 
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->data = data;
    temp->right=NULL;
    temp->left=NULL;

    return temp;
}
```

The above piece of code compiles without any errors.  Why is this so ?

Comment: Format the code. Cite the errors. Tell us your assumptions and expectations.

Comment: Oh really?  "it returned an error"?  Well then, it is so "because".

Comment: `module xy ...` compiled as C code generates an error. Why that? Because it is not valid C code.

Comment: @Anant: Your original code simply violates basic rules of C syntax. That's all there is to it. You can't just write what you want anywhere you want in C. Get a basic book on C - it should explain how/where to write statements in C and perfrom initialization in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot initialize a `struct` member inside a `struct` declaration. You have to do it outside, in your code. The `struct` declaration declares a type, not a variable that can be initialized.

Comment: A `struct` _definition_ can have an initialiser. You mean a `struct` declaration (they are not the same!), resp. a type definition.

Comment: @Olaf: Wrong. C language employs separate concepts of *type definition* and *object definiton*. `struct node { ... }` is a struct type *definition* (i.e. it is a type *declaration* that happens to be a *defintion* as well). Contrary to what you said, *type definitions* cannot include initializers. Only *object definitions* can include initializers.

Comment: @AnT: From my comment: "... resp. a type **definition**". Strictly, it is a _struct-or-union-specifier_. A `struct` declaration is a struct-or-union-specifier plus a declarator. An added initialiser makes that a definition.

Comment: @Olaf: And? One more time: you said that "A `struct` *definition* can have an initialiser". This is not true in context where "struct definition" is meant to refer to *struct type defintion*. What the OP has in their code is a genuine *struct type defintion*. It cannot include initializers. That's indeed the original error.

Comment: @AnT: A `struct` **type** definition is not the same as a `struct` definition (see my comment above).

Comment: @Olaf: That's something you invented yourself. "Struct defintion" is an informal term that can refer to both "struct type defintion" or "struct object defintion", depending on the context. But from the pedantic point of view, "struct defintion" should actually refer to "struct type defintion" specifically. So yes, it is the same, especially if the contexts clearly suggests it, as it clearly does in this case.

Comment: @AnT: If anyone invented some terms, it is the authoritative reference, the C standard. The term `definition` in context of types and objects is clearly defined in 6.7p5. The declaration above does not show a definition in that sense, thus if you call it like that it is not me inventing new semantics. It also does not constitute a type definition. Thus it is just a declaration with a _struct-specifier_ (exactly: _struct-or-union-specifier_). It definitively is not a definition and cannot be one No reason to missuse a well defined term.

Comment: @Olaf: I stand corrected. Indeed, the concept of "type defintion" in C is apparently only applicable to typedef definitions. Struct type declarations are always just declarations (not definitions) regardless of whether the type is complete. Nevertheless, I have to note that I do often enounter C++-like approach to this matter (complete struct type declaration = declaration and definition, incomplete struct type declaration = just declaration) adapted in C-specific texts.

Comment: @AnT: Which is one reason I so massively insist they are different languages. Remember that `struct S` in C++ indeed defines `S` as type-name (implies `typedef struct S S`), in C it is only a `struct` tag. I'm not that comfortable with those details of C++, but I different languages having different semantics is quite common. A more common example is the term "object" which has mutually different meanings for instance in C, C++ and Python (the list certainly can be extended).